Striped row color is exceeding the columns
I have the following code text
to have each employee row in different color. However, the result does not cover all rows.

I tried to change :
<div class="col-1 border-cell dropdown">

to
<div class="col border-cell dropdown">

but the result doesn't have all columns aligned. Please advise.
I tried to adjust to use table tag.


<div class="container mt-5">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="column-name"></th>
                <?php foreach ($dates as $date): ?>
                    <th class="border-cell"><?php echo $date['date']; ?></th>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="column-name"></th>
                <?php foreach ($dates as $date): ?>
                    <th class="border-cell"><?php echo $date['day']; ?></th>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php 
            $employees = ['John Doe', 'Jane Smith', 'Alice Johnson', 'Bob Brown', 'Charlie Davis']; 
            foreach ($employees as $index => $employee): 
                // Determine background color based on row index (striped effect)
                $rowClass = $rowColors[$index % 2]; // Alternate between the two row colors
            ?>
                <tr class="<?php echo $rowClass; ?>">
                    <td class="column-name <?php echo $rowClass; ?>"><?php echo $employee; ?></td>
                    <?php foreach ($dates as $date): 
                        // Randomly select an initial option
                        $randomKey = array_rand($options);
                        $initialValue = $randomKey;
                        $initialClass = $options[$initialValue];
                    ?>
                        <td class="border-cell <?php echo $rowClass; ?>">
                            <div class="dropdown">
                                <button class="btn dropdown-toggle w-100 <?php echo $initialClass; ?>" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                    <?php echo $initialValue; ?> <span class="caret"></span>
                                </button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <?php foreach ($options as $value => $class): ?>
                                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="changeColor(this, '<?php echo $class; ?>')"><?php echo $value; ?></a></li>
                                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>



full code is here

Your data looks tabular. Is there a reason for not using an HTML table?

Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

@AHaworth I want to have difference approach rather than using table. later i want to make it responsive

@fawzan please consider using semantic HTML where applicable - particularly to help those using screen readers.

You have done a lot of mistakes but you might be a beginner. I don't recommend this but you can do one more mistake to fix it. Instead of using the background class on rows you can use it on columns.
The link to the corrected version. link

A better solution is to use table tag and build this.

Yes I am, Thank you, Sir.
Advised by A Haworth to use tabular instead. Would you please leyt me know what's the challenge if continuew using these code approach instead of table?

Strictly, I didn't 'advise' using tables, but asked why they weren't used when the data was obviously tabular. However, please consider those using screen readers and use semantic HTML where possible to help them.

I am sorry, Sir and thank you for the input. So, I adjusted the code to use table tag. It shows horizontal bar at the bottom and when I refresh to mix cell content, the header is wrapped it seems bcs there is maximum column width.

Multiple reason to use table tags,

Screen readers for disabled people
Most importantly good control over layout like automatic uniform column width and row height etc. (without using row, col classes)

